# How to Programmatically Provide and Consume Context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-context

So my question is a simple one. In React js I want to pass some states and handlers from a parent to its 3rd grandchild using Context. I have implemented this within the jsx but I want to use the states within the javascript o that I have some logic before I completely output my states. 
 I have divided my question into 2 parts. 1.) What I have done so far. 2.) What I want to do essentially.

1.)

// this file just stores the Context
MyContext.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export const  MyContext = React.createContext();
```

MyProvider.js // this class is used by the parent and the child to have access to the provider

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {MyContext} from '../MyContext'

class MyProvider extends Component {
    state = {
      name: 'Wes',
      age: 100,
      cool: true
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <MyContext.Provider value={{
          state: this.state,
          growAYearOlder: () => this.setState({
            age: this.state.age + 1
          })
        }}>
          {this.props.children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
      )
    }
  }

  export default MyProvider;
```

// Ok so now I am basically skipping the parent and showing you the consumer grand-child

Person.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// first we will make a new context
import { MyContext } from '../MyContext';



class Person extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="person">
        <MyContext.Consumer>
          {(context) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <p>Age: {context.state.age}</p>
              <p>Name: {context.state.name}</p>
              <button onClick={context.growAYearOlder}></button>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </MyContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Person;
```

2.)
// Ok so as you can see here I have had to immediately use the context.growAYearOlder. What I want to do instead is have control of it using javascript and modify it as desired; So something like this:

Child.js

```
const parentContext = MyContext.getContext();
if(somethingHappens){ 
   parentContext().growAYearOlder();
}

return(
// The now rendered component
);
```

I tried something like this but it doesnt work:

```
  MyContext.Consumer.context.growAYearOlder();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many similar questions with proper answers, docs, examples and so on - but this question kept popping up for me.

So, in case you want to get the context value and use it within your component's `render()` just import it (export context itself not only provider) and use `_currentValue` e.g.

```
const contextData = MyContext._currentValue;
```

Note that you still have to wrap your components with your given context provider.

Also note that for function components, you need to use `useContext` e.g.

```
const contextData = useContext(MyContext);
```

And for class components you can assign the context to a static var and then use it e.g.

```
class Main extends React.Component(){

  static contextType = MyContext;
  
  componentDidMount(){
    const contextData = this.context;
  }

  render() {
     return (
        <p>Hey</p>
     );
  }
```

**Note** that the static var **has to be called** `contextType` otherwise `this.context` won't hold the `MyContext` data.

Answer (score 0):

I've based my answer solely from the docs itself(https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MyContext } from '../MyContext'

class MyProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        // I've moved the state declaration inside the constructor
        this.state = {
          name: 'Wes',
          age: 100,
          cool: true
        }

        // moved the function here and added prevState
        this.growAYearOlder = () => {
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            age: prevState.age + 1,
          }))
        };
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <MyContext.Provider value={{
          state: this.state,
          growAYearOlder: this.growAYearOlder,
        }}>
          {this.props.children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
      )
    }
}

export default MyProvider;
```

Comment: Ok so how does the child consume in your example. This is very similar functionality that my provided code provides already. What I want is to be able to access the context values outside the render function.

Comment: pass the context object within the scope of Context.Consumer? like you pass it to onClick? `onClick={() => handleClick(context)}` and do your thing within that handleClick function?

Comment: It seems that you want to use context out of its scope when you could just use a simple react state management? You have to remember context === global. Context was design to provide/consume rather than just another local state handling. Read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context

Comment: Ok I dont understand how your solution solves the problem I presented above. I want to use and modify params found in the parent inside its child components. I know for sure that I can simply set an onclick method inside the scope of consumer. Dont focus right now on my code and what it is expected to do. It is just and example. Essentially I want to be able to modify the parent's state values and use its functions in a child class. I also want to be able to decide when I can use said parameters logically. This can only happen before the return method. Look at part 2 of my question. Thanks

Comment: Hmm.. Sorry, having some troubles trying to grasp but maybe the docs that I've linked might help you. You might be trying to overkill the concept of context

Comment: Thanks for the help. I looked at the links you provided and I believe that you might not have understood my question.